# What does override do here?

Tags: scala, overriding

What does the `override` do here? After deleting `override`, I can still compile the program.

```
abstract class Animal {
 def name: String
}

class Cat extends Pet {
  override def name: String = "Cat"
}
```

Adapted from Tour of Scala: Upper Type Bounds:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/upper-type-bounds.html

Comment: Yeah since you are not really overriding it is not necessary, still many people _(me included)_ like to use the `override` keyword to point out the fact that such method was defined in the parent class / trait - for the record, there was once a proposal of adding `implement` together to `override` exactly for this case, but it didn't got much traction.

Comment: Adding `override` is often recommended by linters. The idea is that if the top class was to remove the method, this would raise a compilation error and be useful for you to know, like if the method is renamed in the top class.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this is a particular case where removing it does not affect the program. Why `override` is allowed here is for various flexibility reasons:

- say you want to add an implementation in the parent class `Animal` - that would work without affecting the behavior of `Cat` because you used the prophylactic
  `override` in `Cat` to prevent that idea from affecting your extended class. So the subclass becomes just a little bit less tightly-coupled from your base class in this case.
- say someone else deletes the abstract method `name` or renames it in the parent class (without knowing that method is being overridden). This would raise compile errors in all classes that overridden it, to he/she will know that this change should be thoroughly thought before being done, as it will affect the interface and the way clients interact with your code.
- also it makes the compiler help you catch typos in subclasses: say you created another subclass and add a different method but misspell `name` for something else, say `nme` - you'll see that if you used `override` the compiler will warn you that `nme` does not override anything in the base class. (Thanks compiler!)
- for me personally, using `override` in subclasses acts as a *marker* so I *know* that this method is also defined in the base class, without having to manually check the base class, which usually resides in a different file.

So it's more of a "best practice" thing rather than a necessity in this case, and everyone is free to use it as they see fit.